# Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, regression, prediction

I am not an R expert. I am trying to compute the bias generated by the polynomial model:

```
f <- function(x) sin(x-5)/(x-5)
# From which we can sample datasets:
N <- 20
x <- runif(N,0,15)              
t <- f(x) + rnorm(N, sd=0.1)
```

t is the function which is the generating the data, I use a sync function with gaussian error of standard deviation of 0.2.
To create the points x I use the Uniform distribution form 0 to 15.

```
plot.bias <- function (f, polydeg) {
   plot(data.frame(x, t))
   curve(f, type="l", col="green", add=TRUE)
   polyfit <- lm(t ~ poly(x, polydeg, raw=TRUE))
   p <- polynom(coef(polyfit))
   curve(p, col="red", add=TRUE)
   points(x, calc.bias(f, polydeg, x), col="blue")
   abline(h=0, col='blue')
}
```

This is the function which plots first the data, then the original generator curve, next it computes a regression polynomial of a given degree, plots it, and finally plots the bias. The bias is calculated by the following function which gives the error:

```
calc.bias <- function (f, polyfit, point) {
  predictions <- numeric(0)
  print(class(point))
  for (i in 1:100)
  {
     x <- runif(N, 0, 15)                 
     t <- f(x) + rnorm(N, sd=0.2)
     d <- data.frame(point)
     add <- predict(polyfit, newdata = data.frame(point))
     predictions <- c(predictions, add)
  }
  return((f(point)-mean(predictions))^2)
}
```

What I do is to calculate the difference of the best prediction (f function) minus the prediction of a given point in 100 different datasets with our polynomial model. I store these results in the predictions vector and finally the function returns the square of the mean of the differences, which is the squared bias.

It strange that when I execute plain code, not in functions, it works, it does not generate any error. But when I run:

```
plot.bias(f, 1)
```

The error arises. What is wrong? Many tnx

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: In the function `predict` you use the variable `polydeg` which is 1. But, in `predict` the first parameter needs to be a model object for which prediction is desired. e.g. a model from `lm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it. This seems to work, but not sure it his what you expect. In `plot.bias` I changed your use of `calc.bias`, (i.e. `calc.bias(f, polyfit, x)` instead of `calc.bias(f, polydeg, x)`). The whole code I used:

```
library(PolynomF)

f <- function(x) sin(x-5)/(x-5)
# From which we can sample datasets:
N <- 20
x <- runif(N,0,15)              
t <- f(x) + rnorm(N, sd=0.1)  



calc.bias <- function (f, polyfit, point) {
  predictions <- numeric(0)
  print(class(point))
  for (i in 1:100)
  {
    x <- runif(N, 0, 15)                 
    t <- f(x) + rnorm(N, sd=0.2)
    d <- data.frame(point)
    add <- predict(polyfit, newdata = data.frame(point))
    predictions <- c(predictions, add)
  }
  return((f(point)-mean(predictions))^2)
}

plot.bias <- function (f, polydeg) {
  plot(data.frame(x, t))
  curve(f, type="l", col="green", add=TRUE)
  polyfit <- lm(t ~ poly(x, polydeg, raw=TRUE))
  p <- polynom(coef(polyfit))
  curve(p, col="red", add=TRUE)
  points(x, calc.bias(f, polyfit, x), col="blue")
  abline(h=0, col='blue')
}

plot.bias(f, 1)
```

Comment: Yes, now it works, but as you have pointed out, it is not what I expected. The bias does not change with the degree of the polynomial...

Comment: I'am not sure if your `calc.bias` is correct. At the moment it calculates 100 times the same prediction, because it uses `point` which does not change.